Help with iBUS Telemetry Adapter Build and Zener Diode Replacement
I'm working on building the iBUS telemetry adapter from this repository. I've got most of the required materials, but I’m stuck on sourcing the 1N4142 Zener diode. It’s proving difficult to find here in Europe.
My questions:
Is there a good alternative to the 1N4142 Zener diode that I could use in this project?
Could someone help me with creating an electrical schematic for the build? I didn’t see one in the repository.
Thanks in advance for any assistance!
